# supremum norm and submultiplicativity

Tags: analysis, normed-spaces

If $f$, $g \in C(S)$ where $S$ is a compact set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then it is true that $$\lVert fg \rVert \leq \lVert f \rVert \lVert g \rVert$$
where the norm is the usual supremum norm. 
Why is this not true if $S$ is not compact? What other conditions can $S$ satisfy so that this is true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is true if $S$ is not compact, but the issue is that continuous functions on noncompact spaces may not be bounded, and so the supremum will not exist (although it could be defined to be $\infty$, but this is not a real number) and so the supremum norm is not a norm.

Answer (score 3):

If $C(S)$ denotes the set of continuous functions on a space $S$, then in order for the sup norm to make sense, every continuous function on $S$ must be bounded.  For subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$, this is equivalent to compactness.

If $X$ is an arbitrary set and $f,g:X\to\mathbb R$ are arbitrary *bounded* functions, then you can prove that $\sup\limits_{x\in X}|fg(x)|\leq\sup\limits_{x\in X}|f(x)|\sup\limits_{x\in X}|g(x)|$,  by showing that the right-hand side of the inequality is an upper bound for the set $\{|f(x)g(x)|:x\in X\}$.

Comment: "then you can prove that $sup_{x∈X}|fg(x)|≤sup_{x∈X}|f(x)|sup_{x∈X}|g(x)|$, by showing that the right-hand side of the inequality is an upper bound", So am I saying sup$|fg(x)| = |f(x)| |g(x)|$?. please clarify, I feel I am missing some concept.

Comment: @GaurangChauhan No, but if $x_0\in X$  then $|fg(x_0)|=|f(x_0)||g(x_0)|\leq \sup\limits_{x\in X}|f(x)|\sup\limits_{x\in X}|g(x)|$. Since $x_0$ was arbitrary the inequality  $\sup\limits_{x\in X}|fg(x)|\leq\sup\limits_{x\in X}|f(x)|\sup\limits_{x\in X}|g(x)|$ follows.

Answer (score 2):

It is true.  This is a general property of suprema of functions.  Suppose $f$ and $g$ are defined on an arbitrary set $\Omega$.  Then

$$|f(x)g(x)| \le |f(x)|\sup_{x\in\Omega}|g(x)| \le \sup_{x\in\Omega} |f(x)| \sup_{x\in\Omega}|g(x)|.$$

Since $x\in \Omega$ was chosen arbitrarily, your inequality follows right away.

This, however, will not be a norm unless you restrict yourself to bounded functions.  The compactness of $S$ gives you this  boundedness.